# How to view if a resource was created by a Azure service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-group, azure-service-principal

I logged into azure using az login --service-principal and created a resource group. How to find out the audit trail which says that the resource group was created by a service principal? When I go for "Audit Logs", it mentions that my own user id has created it. How can that be possible? Why is it reporting that I created it, when the truth is that I used the client id and secret to login and create the resource group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are using the `az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID` to sign in with the service principal.

After creating the resource group by `az group create -l westus -n AllenTestRGroup008`, I open **Activity log** and see that there is only one operation here:

[image]

The **Event initiated by** is the caller of this operation. So in my case, **testMultiMSA** is the service principal who creates the resource group.

If I click on the log for more details, I can find the `caller` property in JSON. It is the object id of the service principal.

[image]

You can have a check from your side.

Comment: Hi Allen, It didn't work for me. I still see that the user created is myself and not the service principal !
There are two differences though.
1. MY service principal tenant does not have a subscription. So I used the parameter --allow-no-subscription
2. When creating the RG, I used the --subscription "subsid" with the az group command to create the rg in the subscription where the SP has Contributor access.

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran I don't understand that if your service principal tenant does not have a subscription, how the SP will have Contributor access to a subscription? Where is this subscription from?

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran OK I got what you mean based on your previous post. Let me have a test.

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran But I still cannot assign Contributor role of the subscription in Tenant A to a service principal in Tenant B. How do you make it? (the step 4 in your pervious post)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to test it out. I go the Access Control IAM of the Subscription in Tenant A -> go to role assignment -> Search the service principle/app and then select it to have it assigned. One other thing is, the service principal was created as a part of app registration in tenant B. Tenant A is my organization AD and they wont let me create Svc principals there. Hence I resorted to creating my own AD/tenant. I am sorry if my explanation is confusing you.

Comment: Looks like it was a mistake from my side. The service principal name that I used in Tenant A, is also available in the Tenant B as the service principal. Due to the same name, I was misled into believing that they were same. You are right that the service principal from tenant A cannot be given contributor role in tenant B.